# PyCharm Python Lambda Event Bridge missing AWSEvent

Tags: python, aws-lambda, pycharm, aws-sam, aws-event-bridge

I am trying to setup a basic AWS Lambda in pycharm based on an AWS Event Bridge schema. However after generating the framework code and attempting to run the Lambda it is complaining about a failing import on:

```
from schema.payload_report_event import AWSEvent
```

```
{"errorType":"Runtime.ImportModuleError","errorMessage":"Unable to import module 'hello_world/app': cannot import name 'AWSEvent' from 'schema.payload_report_event' (/var/task/schema/payload_report_event/__init__.py)"}
```

```
# Deserialize event into strongly typed object
aws_event: AWSEvent = Marshaller.unmarshall(event, AWSEvent)
detail: PayrollReportRequest = aws_event.detail

# Execute business logic

# Make updates to event payload, if desired
aws_event.detail_type = "HelloWorldFunction updated event of " + aws_event.detail_type

# Return event for further processing
return Marshaller.marshall(aws_event)
```

Any suggestions on how I can resolve this. That class is certainly not generated in the file dir.

Comment: `AWSEvent` is not an installable module, but is included in the AWS SAM EventBridge example(s) (which you found).  A copy of all the templates downloaded by `sam init` can be found in `$HOME/.aws-sam/`, or you can check the repository at 
[https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli-app-templates](https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli-app-templates).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to find a workaround by generating a new project based on a different SAM template:

[image]

Rather than the from Scratch (for an Event schema) option. In this case the aws_event.py file is generated and can be modified to have the appropriate Detail type set. This does seem to be a bug somewhere along the line in the tooling though so will check the issue trackers and try submit to relevant project.